# How can I get the number of times an enttry in a table was listed

Tags: lua, lua-table, roblox

I need to find a way to see how many times an entry is listed in a table.

I have tried looking at other code for help, and looking at examples online none of them help

```lua
local pattern = "(.+)%s?-%s?(.+)"

local table = {"Cald_fan:1", "SomePerson:2", "Cald_fan:3","anotherPerson:4"}

for i,v in pairs(table) do
    local UserId, t = string.match(v, pattern)

    for i,v in next,UserId do
        --I have tried something like this
    end
end
```

it is suppose to say Cald_fan was listed 2 times

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
local pattern = "(.+)%s*:%s*(%d+)"
local tbl = {"Cald_fan:1", "SomePerson:2", "Cald_fan:3","anotherPerson:4"}
local counts = {}

for i,v in pairs(tbl) do
    local UserId, t = string.match(v, pattern)
    counts[UserId] = 1 + (counts[UserId] or 0)
end
print(counts['Cald_fan']) -- 2
```

I renamed `table` to `tbl` (as using `table` variable makes the table.* functions not available) and fix the pattern (you had unescaped '-' in it, while your strings had ':').

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your table entries is consistent, you can simply split the strings apart and use the components as keys in a map of counters.

It looks like your table entries are formatted as "[player_name]:[index]", but it doesn't look like you care about the index. But, if the ":" will be in every table entry, you can write a pretty reliable search pattern. You could try something like this :

```
-- use a list of entries with the format <player_name>:<some_number>
local entries = {"Cald_fan:1", "SomePerson:2", "Cald_fan:3","anotherPerson:4"}
local foundPlayerCount = {}

-- iterate over the list of entries
for i,v in ipairs(entries) do
    -- parse out the player name and a number using the pattern :
    -- (.+) = capture any number of characters
    -- :    = match the colon character
    -- (%d+)= capture any number of numbers 
    local playerName, playerIndex = string.match(v, '(.+):(%d+)')

    -- use the playerName as a key to count how many times it appears
    if not foundPlayerCount[playerName] then
        foundPlayerCount[playerName] = 0
    end
    foundPlayerCount[playerName] = foundPlayerCount[playerName] + 1
end

-- print out all the players
for playerName, timesAppeared in pairs(foundPlayerCount) do
    print(string.format("%s was listed %d times", playerName, timesAppeared))
end
```

If you need to do pattern matching in the future, I highly recommend this article on lua string patterns : http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

Hope this helps!